# Eclipse blocks saving tab

Tags: c++, eclipse

In eclipse, some undiscovered key combination makes current tab's title gray and disables <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. To save the current file I have to press "X" on the tab to close it, provoking the "save-on-exit" window where I can press "Yes", file saves. Why?

SOLVED: just activate another window and switch to Eclipse window again (-;